# MMQGIS doesnt recognize header columns

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

When I try the geocoding function in QGIS plugin mmqgis it doesn´t recognize my columns headers and when I try to fill in the fields, it only recognizes the whole

[image: Qgis Field problem]

The CSV has around 200 entries.

Does someone know a workaround?

Comment: That looks a bit weird for me. Have tried the same and it works. Can you tell please how did you achieve you `csv`-file, e.g. from Excel, Python processing etc.? By the way, will you be able to share a sample of your data in `csv`?

Comment: I exported the excel data file to CSV, but due to limitation in excel 2013 I had to open it up in notepad and save it as UTF 08. I tried a CSV with repetitive data and more entries, and that worked I made a screenshot https://i.imgur.com https://i.imgur.com/EIr5E4C.png/nMwbweY.png I am not alowed to share the data because of private information in it. I already removed the empty cells with unknown but that still doesnt solve it,

Comment: I figured it out Taras, there were some cells which had characters like ""   *** that messed with the CSV I think, thanks alot for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. There were some cells which had characters like `""`, `***` that messed with the `CSV`.